# How to show popup window over dialog Android

Tags: android

I need help. I want to show a popup window over dialog.

On API 23 i did it. But on API >23 i can do this. See images.

[API > 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVPZY.png)

[API < 23](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw491.png)

Thanks for help.

Comment: you can try follwing library  https://github.com/sephiroth74/android-target-tooltip

Comment: Thank you. I will check and reply.

Comment: I have checked but it don't work for me. I want popup over dialog like
API < 23. Do you have another solution?

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

@TuNguyen Not sure if you're still looking for an answer but for people who're still facing this: I resolved it using the ([**`WindowLayoutType`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#setWindowLayoutType(int))) for the popupWindow. Adding this works:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    popupWindow.windowLayoutType = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_ATTACHED_DIALOG

//Refer to the android's doc I attached above for the complete list of WindowLayouts
}

//I am using Kotlin
```